# Java Socket ArrayList NullPointer Exception

Tags: sockets, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Whenever I run my Chat Server it works until the client connects and then I get a Null Pointer exception at 
connections.add(socket); 
which crashes it and then this happens every time I run it.
I know my client side is fine because I watched a tutorial a few months ago on how to do this and that server works with my client without crashing

```
private static ServerSocket server;
private static Socket socket;
private static Scanner input;
private static PrintWriter output;

private static final int port = 444;
private static String message;
private static ArrayList<Socket> connections;
private static Server serverClass;

public Server() {

    message = "";
    connections = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    serverClass = new Server();

}

public void run() {

    try {

        try {

            input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            while(true) {

                checkConnection();

                if(!input.hasNext()) {

                    return;

                }

                message = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Client said: " + message);

                for(int i = 1; i <= connections.size(); i++) {

                    Socket tempSock = (Socket) connections.get(i - 1);
                    output.println(message);
                    output.flush();

                }

            }

        }
        finally {

            socket.close();

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.print(e);

    }

}

public void checkConnection() throws IOException {

    if(!socket.isConnected()) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= connections.size(); i++) {

            if(connections.get(i) == socket) {

                connections.remove(i);

            }

        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= connections.size(); i++) {

            Socket disconnectedUser = (Socket) connections.get(i - 1);
            System.out.println(disconnectedUser + " has Disconnected!");

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    try {

        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for Clients... ");

        while(true) {

            socket = server.accept();
            connections.add(socket);
            System.out.println("Client connected from: " + socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName());

            Thread thread = new Thread(serverClass);
            thread.start();

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: did you debug and see if there are any values in connections?

Comment: @mdoran3844 He is accepting the socket, not connecting it. Unless you are incorrectly asserting that `ArrayList` cannot have null elements, your question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

If you get an NPE at `connections.add(socket),` it can only be because `connections` is null. Which it is, because you haven't constructed an instance of `Server`: instead you are trying to execute all its code from `main().` The only place you call `new Server()` from is inside the constructor for `Server,` which you have clearly never executed at all, as you would have got a `StackOverflowError` from the infinite recursion.

This code is a real mess:

- fix the infinite recursion
- construct an instance of `Server` in your `main()` method
- make `connections` non-static
- make `socket` a local variable in the accept loop
- fix your loops to iterate from 0 to `connections.size()-1`

and try again.